# How to get text value from DOM Element in Tapestry 5

Tags: java, dom, tapestry

Accroding to this http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/dom/Element.html there is no method for get raw text data from DOM element. So how can I get text recursively from all child elements? The `Element.visit(Visitor visitor)` method is much good for going deep into the children, but what about text?

Comment: You can't. Try `Node.toString` or `Element.getChildMarkup`. What you really want is access to the underlying DOM objects and `Node.textContent` but who knows how you get that.